# Как сделать безопасный запрос PHP-MySQL

Tags: php, запрос, mysql

Начинаю изучать веб-дизайн. Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой. У меня есть новостная лента, к которой делается запрос вида

```
SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = {$_GET['id']}
```

Мне сказали, что это небезопасно, так как здесь происходит прямая SQL-инъекция. Как от этого можно избавиться?

Comment: запросы происходят таким образом:
$MyQuery = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id='{$_POST['id']}';";
$Result = mysqli_query($this->db,$MyQuery);

Comment: вам [сюда](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем случае, не привязанном к определённому модулю или расширению для работы с БД, можно [фильтровать входные параметры](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php). Например, вы ожидаете, что `id` может быть только целым числом, тогда подойдёт:

```
$id = filter_input ( INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
// если не установлено расширение для фильтрации, 
// в данном случае, с только-целыми-числами, достаточно следующей строки
// $id приводится к типу "целое", инъекции не пройдут:
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = ' . (int)$id;
```

Я нисколько не умаляю необходимость использовать prepared statements везде, где это возможно. Ссылки ещё раз: подготовленные запросы [в PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php) и [в MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.prepare.php), как самых распостранённых.

Answer (score 3):

[PDO](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo) вам в помошь.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, почему в России существует дурацкая привычка ссылаться на сторонние ресурсы вместо официальной документации ?